# libgdx how to set alpha on multiple sprites as if it were a single sprite

Tags: opengl, libgdx, sprite, alpha, spritebatch

I'm trying to achieve the effect as shown in (B) of the following image. If I set alpha on the Sprite Batch I end up with the effect as shown in (C). Can anyone please tell me how I can get the desired effect as in (B).

[image]

Please note i'm not trying to mask the sprites. I'm trying to set a global alpha that will affect all sprites drawn after the global alpha has been set. An example of usage would be a dialog that fades in or out.

Comment: The only way I know of to do this would be to draw all of them at full opacity to a FrameBuffer and then draw the FrameBuffer's texture to the screen at partial transparency.

Comment: @Tenfour04: "*draw all of them at full opacity*" Just to make sure we're on the same page, you still need to *write* the alpha. You're just not using the alpha for *blending*.

Comment: I mean that you draw them normally with blending and alpha, but don't reduce their opacity in the first pass by using a vertex color with lowered alpha.

Comment: did you try with the blending mode Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    Gdx.gl20.glBlendFuncSeparate(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is non-trivial. Blending works on a per-triangle basis, after all, and two separate primitives are two *separate* primitives. One will be blended after the other, with no connection between them.

The only *general* way to achieve what you want is to render the sum total of these objects to a separate framebuffer, writing the alpha values of each object, but *without blending*. Note that the separate framebuffer should have an alpha component, and it should have been cleared to 0 before you started writing.

Once you have that separate framebuffer finished, you can then render it as a single quad, using blending (with some added alpha, as you desire).

Comment: Hi, I've tried using pixmaps rendered to textures. This works as desired but has a very high overhead in terms of memory and time. Would a framebuffer be an improvement?